# Excel executing original code after code modified and compiled

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently struggling with Excel and my code. I have a simple for loop that iterates down a column, finds a value, then copies a range, and pastes it in a new range.

Now for the problem. I had originally programmed this as a `Sheets.Range.Cut`, and have change it to a `.Copy`, however, the code is still running the `.Cut` method. Also, important to note that the Debug.Print is not running, but the `.Cut` is still running. Below is an excerpt.

```
'reset date box
For i = 1 To 100
    If Len(wsPMetrics.Range("U" & i)) > 0 Then
        wsPMetrics.Range("U" & i & ":U" & (i + 1)).Copy Sheets("Performance Metrics").Range("U3")
        wsPMetrics.Range("U" & i & ":U" & (i + 1)).Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Debug.Print "Reseting date"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Also, my last for loop in my code is being skipped completely (new addition), and Debug.Print is not executing as well. See excerpt below.

```
'reset totals box
For i = 1 To 100
    If Len(wsPMetrics.Range("W" & i)) > 0 Then
        wsPMetrics.Range("W" & i & ":X" & (i + 3)).Cut Sheets("Performance Metrics").Range("W7")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Debug.Print "Reseting balances"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

I have also altered another block of code from `Range("P")` to `Range("T")`, and the code is executing the original range of P. Below is the code, and note that it was formerly range P but is now range T, but still executes on old range.

```
'draw box around day
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
'            wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
'            wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        wsPMetrics.Range("C3:T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
        
        wsPMetrics.Range("C" & (i + 1) & ":T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        wsPMetrics.Range("C" & (i + 1) & ":T" & (i + 1)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        Debug.Print "Adding borders"
```

Even when I comment out the block of code it is still running the same code, almost as if it has stored it and is not refreshing to the new code. I have compiled the project with the new code and I have also closed and opened the workbook, as made sure that the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`and still the same issue. I have attached a screenshot here to see what I imply by the above. [image: Example]

Any help/ guidance with the above is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't how VBA works. It compiles when you execute it and has no version control so will only execute what is on the screen. I suspect you're either calling a copy of the code from somewhere OR You suspect it is doing a `Cut` as you're `Copy`ing the cells and then `Delete`ing them. Which would look the same

Comment: This does not explain why it is drawing the borders on column P instead of column T. As well as it not running through the second for loop.

Comment: @D.DeVilliers Your first step should be figuring out why your `Debug.Print` isn't returning anything - that's the biggest red flag here, which leads me to agree with Tom that you're just calling this code from another module (maybe from PERSONAL.xlsb by accident?)

Comment: If you are using a button make sure its "assigned" the correct macro

Comment: It would do if you're calling a copy of the code elsewhere. Your `For` loop probably doesn't 'run' as it doesn't meet the `If` statement conditions. If you're commenting out the block of code and the bordering is still happening it suggests a) it is there in the first place and the deletion of ranges moves it into view. b) it is being caused by something else; probably the copy and paste. I'd suggest avoiding copy and paste all together personally. How are you calling the code? Is it via a button or executing it in the VBA Editor? Have you tried stepping through it (Use F8)?

Comment: You should step through the code [F8] and watch each step complete and verify what you want to happen actually happens before proceeding to the next line.  If it doesn't, then you know which line(s) is/are causing your problem.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the guidance, managed to find the problems thanks to it!

Comment: @D.DeVilliers In the future, I would suggest not doing `Len(ws.Range)` because VBA isn't going to understand what you mean by `Len()` if you give it a table range, and a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish would be to use `ws.Range.Rows.Count` for vertical length and `ws.Range.Columns.Count` for horizontal length.